# Return of a false value

Tags: python

The purpose of the following function is to iterate through `foot_bones` looking for a match of the string argument in `search2`.

The input will be taken from the user. The output is

> it is not a footbone

no matter what the input is.

```py
def foot(search2, foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular","lateral cuneiform","intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]):
    for dk in foot_bones:
        if search2.lower() == dk.lower:
            return True
            break
search = input("Enter the bone name")
if foot(search2=search):
    print("the entered bone is a footbone")
else: 
    print("it is not a footbone")
```

Comment: Just FYI, the whole function can be shortened to `search2.lower() in foot_bones`. (You have to work a bit harder if `foot_bones` entries are not lowercase to start with, though.)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the parentheses after `dk.lower`, therefore you compare `search2.lower()` to the `lower` method of `dk` instead of the lowercase foot bone.

Change that line to:

```py
if search2.lower() == dk.lower():
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also shorten your code by doing...

```
def foot(...):
    return search2.lower() in foot_bones
```